# html/css: png losing transparency on border of a cut out(in browser only)

Tags: html, css, png

### edit:

seems to be mac/chrome related problem, works fine on win/chrome, mac/safari, mac/firefox

http://jsbin.com/bezibu/1/edit?html,css,output

You can see a white border inside the cut out in browser.

[image]

closeup:

[image]

same thing in photoshop, no white border

[image]

closeup:

[image]

Any idea why is this happening and how to prevent it?

Whether it's as a background image or `<img>` doesn't seem to matter..

Comment: What browser?   I examined your link with both IE9 and Chrome and don't see the border?

Comment: Chrome 42.0.2311.68 beta (64-bit) on mac, seems to be working fine on safari/firefox.. so it's chrome only it would seem

Comment: If you still haven't found an answer I will take a look at it on my Mac when I get home.   It is fine on Chrome 41.0.2272.118 m on the PC.

Comment: tried different png settings in photoshop.. it only got worse, not even sure whether it's even case of losing transparency, it seems to be creating artificial borders beyond the transparent part.. http://i.imgur.com/KmxAQej.png

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26243/why-does-chrome-distort-my-transparent-png-adding-a-subtle-inset-weak-area retina could be the reason why it bugs out

Comment: Definitely must be a display issue?   It is fine on my late 2012 27" iMac in Chrome 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit)

Comment: That's not retina then. Retina means some 220 PPI. 2012 27" iMac has 100, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, haven't had enough motivation to spring for an 5K iMac yet.  :-)   Well, sorry I couldn't find a resolution (no pun intended) to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem happens on retine-esque displays only. Solution is to double the size of the PNG and use `background-size`.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=475227